# Cybersource soap toolkit api avoid redirection on 3rd party domain

Tags: python, soap-client, cybersource

I am implementing soap toolkit api. After submitting credit card info it redirects me towards the 3rd party page to get the password. I want to avoid that redirection is it possible to load that page within my domain or on my custom page using IFRAME.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to render it inside an iframe. Assuming you've called ics_pa_enroll to get the pareq and ACS URL you'd do something like this:

```
<body>
    <form action="[ACS URL]" method="POST" target="payerAuthFrame">
        <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="[Returned PaReq]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="[Whatever]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="[Your Site]" />
    </form>
    <iframe name="payerAuthFrame" width="800" height="800"></iframe>
</body>
```

and either have the customer submit the form with e.g. a "Proceed" button or else use JavaScript to submit it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer but more of a request for clarifying information: When you say "it redirects me towards the 3rd party page to get the password", are you talking about the 3D-Secure process?  I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but in order to use 3D Secure, I think the idea is to guide the end-user through the process of the additional Verification (security) process. So I think the redirection is required as a matter of how the Business Process (or 3D-Secure) works.

Comment: But I have seen some cases where this verification window appends inside the customers checkout page. any ideas ?